# Paging next/previous links with Google escape fragment

Tags: seo, google, ajax, pagination

I have paging URLs below and the page uses AJAX to do paging. Do I need to add `_escaped_fragment_=` to the URL below or are those URLs fine?

```
<link rel="prev" href="http://example.com/youth-basketball-tournaments/kansas?page=4" />
<link rel="prev" href="http://example.com/youth-basketball-tournaments/kansas?page=5" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your URLs look fine as they are.

You should never have to link to an `_escaped_fragment_` URL.   Those URLs should only be created by Googlebot from your canonical URLs.

You use `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` in those pages, so Googlebot will know to fetch the escaped fragment for them.